# Sorting Array with Zero values Last using array_multisort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

am trying to sort some students' total marks with ascending and total grades with descending,using array_multisort it works except, I have one challenge, a student with both zero total grades and marks tops up. I need the student to be last on the list.

```
    $vc_array=array(
      0 => 
        array(
              'student_name' =>  'student one',
              'total' =>  227,
              'total_grades' =>  27),
        1 => 
        array(
              'student_name' =>  'student two',
              'total' =>  313,
              'total_grades' =>  14),
        2 => 
        array(
              'student_name' =>  'student three',
              'total' =>  317,
              'total_grades' =>  13),
        3 => 
        array (
              'student_name' =>  'student four' ,
              'total' =>  271,
              'total_grades' =>  20),
        4 => 
        array (
              'student_name' =>  'student five',
              'total' =>  0,
              'total_grades' =>  0));


    foreach ($vc_array as $key => $row)
{
   $vc_array_value[$key] = $row['total_grades'];
   $vc_array_name[$key] = $row['total'];
 }
array_multisort($vc_array_value, SORT_ASC, $vc_array_name, SORT_DESC, vc_array);
```

when I run var_dump($vc_array); it out put this....

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'student_name' => string 'student five' (length=12)
      'total' => int 0
      'total_grades' => int 0
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'student_name' => string 'student three' (length=13)
      'total' => int 317
      'total_grades' => int 13
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'student_name' => string 'student two' (length=11)
      'total' => int 313
      'total_grades' => int 14
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'student_name' => string 'student four' (length=12)
      'total' => int 271
      'total_grades' => int 20
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'student_name' => string 'student one' (length=11)
      'total' => int 227
      'total_grades' => int 27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one way to get around this is to [filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) out the values where both `total` and `total_grades` are 0 in `$vc_array` and store those in a separate array.

Then perform the sorting and at the end merge the array where both values are zero to `$vc_array`.

```
$totalZero = [];
$vc_array = array_filter($vc_array, function($x) use (&$totalZero) {
    if ($x['total'] === 0 && $x['total_grades'] === 0) {
        $totalZero[] = $x;
    }
    return $x['total'] !== 0 || $x['total_grades'] !== 0;
});

foreach ($vc_array as $key => $row)
{
    $vc_array_value[$key] = $row['total_grades'];
    $vc_array_name[$key] = $row['total'];
}

array_multisort($vc_array_value, SORT_ASC, $vc_array_name, SORT_DESC, $vc_array);
$vc_array = array_merge($vc_array, $totalZero);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ASlKj)

Comment: thanks bro...your method is short and simple... otherwise I had added another item in the array:  'division'=>'X' then I sorted using three keys. But i guess I'll go with your method, short n simple thanks @The Fourth Bird

Answer (score 0):

This task can be completed with absolutely no pre-processing of the data.

`usort()` will happily sort by multiple rules according to related elements on either side of the three-way comparison operator ("spaceship operator": `<=>`).

1. Sort by `total_grades` cast as a boolean in descending order (this way trues are placed before falses), then
2. Sort by `total_grades` in ascending order, then
3. Sort by `total` in descending order (not that it mattered for your sample data)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aLIin))

```
usort(
    $vc_array,
    fn($a, $b) => 
        [(bool) $b['total_grades'], $a['total_grades'], $b['total']]
        <=>
        [(bool) $a['total_grades'], $b['total_grades'], $a['total']]
);
var_export($vc_array);
```

The simple thing to remember is that `a <=> b` means ascending and `b <=> a` means descending.  I should also mention that `true` is treated as `1` and `false` is treated as `0` when making boolean comparisons.

---

If you adamantly demand the use of `array_multisort()`, then populate 3 sorting arrays in advance.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AnVUj))

```
$bools = [];
$grades = [];
$totals = [];
foreach ($vc_array as ['total' => $total, 'total_grades' => $grade]) {
    $bools[] = (bool) $grade;
    $grades[] = $grade;
    $totals[] = $total;
}
array_multisort($bools, SORT_DESC, $grades, $totals, SORT_DESC, $vc_array);
var_export($vc_array);
```